# Eigen Matrix of Vector3d gives strange error

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I need container of 3D vectors and tried this:

```
//typedef Eigen::Matrix<Vector3d, -1, 1> Field3X;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<Vector3d, Dynamic, 1>  Field3X;
Field3X vecMat(3);
Vector3d v(1.0,3.0,4.0);

vecMat(0)=  v;
vecMat(1) = v;
vecMat(2) = v;
cout << "Here is vecMat:\n" << vecMat << endl;
```

Calling `cout` line gives strange error:

```
Error   3   error C2665: 'log10' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all 
the argument types  d:\eigen-eigen-
5a0156e40feb\eigen\src\Core\NumTraits.h 34  1
```

What is better way to have array of `Vector3d` objects?
p.s. yes I know, I can use stl vector with alignment macro, but which one is better for faster access an manipulations?

Comment: Why not using Eigen::Matrix3d directly?

Comment: I need 2d aray of 3d vectors....This worked   `Vector3d v(1.0, 3.0, 4.0);
 MatrixXd ma = MatrixXd(3,10);
 ma.array().fill(0);
 ma.col(0) = v;
 ma.col(1) = v;
 ma.col(2) = v;
 ma.col(3) = v;
 ma.col(4) = v;
 cout << "m:\n" << ma<< endl;`  So this works for 2darray . In general I need 3D array of vectors...How to make it?

Comment: I can pack it in `MatrixXd(3,N)`, where `N=sizeX*sizeY*sizeZ;' , but this is `c++ way` :) ..can this be done in `Eigen` style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream output operator `<<` is not defined / overlaoded for the type that you want to display. You can use this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vecMat.size(); ++i) {
 cout << "Here is vecMat(" << i << "):\n" << vecMat(i) << endl;
}
```